# why to make directive in angularjs not renderning second time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

why my google directive not working ? Actually I make a simple directive of google map .And display on view.it work first time .But not work for second time .I will explain more When I run my plunker it show me Qutub minar google map.But when I click 
**‘+’** icon and press **done button** add another location example “Delhi” it give me longitude and latitute but not display the map

here is my code

Issue on this fuction I think

```
this.loadMap = function(latLng) {
                console.log("function latlng called");
                console.log(latLng);
                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);


                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("id"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two major troubles :

1. You generate multiple div with the same id (googleMap).
2. When you run the directive it get element by id but there is multiple elements with this ID which cause it to mess.

The main problem is that generating the google-map shouldn't be the responsibility of your "pane" directive but should be a totally new directive instead.

You can see it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sm4igjt7aZOJPSHEb0k8?p=preview) :

What i did :

I create a new directive `myGoogleMap` which basically use your old `loadMap` function (That i removed from the `tabs` directive). I also took the "latlng" attribute from the pane and put it on this directive.

```
.directive('myGoogleMap', function(){
 return {
    scope: {
            latlng: '='
        },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs){
     var latLng = scope.latlng;
      console.log("function latlng called");
      console.log(latLng);
      google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
      var myCenter;
      myCenter=null;
       myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
      var mapProp = {
          center: myCenter,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapProp);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myCenter,
      });

      marker.setMap(map);
    }
   }
```

The main difference is that the directive that generate the google map is already on the good element. I'll be able to access this element with `element[0]` in the link function. That mean i can actually generate a google map everywhere else giving a `latlng` object and using this directive.

Now your `ng-repeat` for `pane` looks like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="tabInfo in tabPlaces.tabItems" pane title="{{ tabInfo.title}}" ng-show="tabInfo.selected">
    <p>{{ tabInfo.content }}</p>
    <div my-google-map latlng="tabInfo.latlng" ng-style="mapConfig" style="height:200px;width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I think the OP wants to add Delhi, not replace Qutub Minar, so you should see both, from looking at the code.

Comment: @camden_kid Crap that may be true. I though this because he have a ng-show on each pane and each pane contain a google-map. Clicking on a tab hide a pane (and its map) and display an other one. So i guessed each pane have a google map with a location. We need more precision from the OP then. Hopping i felt the good one.

Comment: I don't want both at one time

Comment: could you please explain more what you did ..I understand the problem of ID ..mean I am taking same ID ? I am correct

Comment: @user944513 in fact to be exact, using document.getElementById() isn't a great practice in angular. On your code your ng-repeat will create the "<div id="googlemap">" for each "tabInfo in tabPlaces.tabItems" that mean you will have some <div> with the exact same id. document.getElementById() will always just return you the first one. (that in you case is actually hidden when you are on some other pane).